# Delete a Class Instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, instance, es6-class

I'm trying to delete an instance of a class.

I have a `<button>` tag with an event listener a class method `remove`:

```
<msg-item>
    <span>username: {{this.username}}</span>
    <p>message: {{this.message}}</p>
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.remove()">delete</button>
<msg-item>
<msg-item>
    <span>username: {{this.username}}</span>
    <p>message: {{this.message}}</p>
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.remove()">delete</button>
<msg-item>
<msg-item>
    <span>username: {{this.username}}</span>
    <p>message: {{this.message}}</p>
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.remove()">delete</button>
<msg-item>
```

The class:

```
class msgItemCtrl{
    constructor(){
        this.username = "johndoe";
        this.message = "hello world";
    }
    remove(){
        console.log('FIRING: Class Method (remove)');
        delete this;
    }
}
```

**Question:** How can I delete the instance of the class as well  as the associated HTML from the interface?

Comment: What `delete` does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: You can't delete variables or object instances (like `delete this` or `delete myVariable`), you can only remove properties from an object (like `delete this.something` or `delete myVariable.something`).

Comment: Javascript uses a garbage collector, you don't need to worry about deleting to save memory etc..  if nothing references this class, then the class will destroy on it's own.

Comment: @adeneo no `this` references the object

Comment: @Frxstrem yeah thats what I read on MDN but I need it to be removed from the interface. If I delete the `object.props` like `username,password` the html is still on the interface

Comment: @Keith Yeah I've also read that but, again it doesn't remove it from the interface, so even if delete all props referencing it, the html is still there.

Comment: @adeneo it's not Angular that does it, it's the new ES6 Classes, it handles the `this` variable differently.

Comment: What interface?..   If you mean the HTML, then it's the HTML part you delete,..  I must admit I'm not an anuglarjs user, but no matter what back end framework you use, you don't delete classes..  ES6 classes, are just sugar on top on Javascript function prototypes, nothing more.

Comment: @Keith nor am I, I like coding to js standards but manager at work only can code w/ angular lol.... anyway, yeah interface I meant HTML.

Comment: So are you trying to just remove the button

Comment: @adeneo I'm trying to delete the "component" angular term... which basically means a block of HTML `<div>[span,button,etc..]</div>` ...so deleting the `div` parent deleting all of it.

Comment: Removing the element is generally just `element.remove();`, no need to do anything to the class ?

Comment: @adeneo yeah no shit lol, but you would need to pass reference of the element to do so, in classes you instantiate the object, so you don't need to run reference. It should know already that the `element.remove` is applied to the root `component` tag for that particular instance, in this case `msg-item`.

Comment: Well, Angular is the devils work, and using classes for something as simple as an event handler that removes an element, sure does complicate things, doesn't it.

Comment: Anyway, I guess you have to pass the event, use `$event.currentTarget` etc. and go from there.

Comment: @adeneo completely agree about angular! lmao. Yes this is a simple example, but no the whole reason of classes is so you don't need to pass reference to the `parent-node` object.

Comment: @adeneo yeah I have in the pass been passing `e.target` then traversing upward from the trigger element and returning the first occurrence of whatever pattern, so in this case it would return `msg-item` the tag then I can preform a `document.removeElement` but thats the old school way now.

Comment: I have no idea how to get that parentNode inside the class, but someone else probably does, and once you have it, it should work with jQLite's `remove()` as well

Comment: @adeneo forsure yeah me either thats why I'm asking I've seen others do it, and I've done it myself... but again with pure JS, not something created by the Devil himself lmao.